# Emacs portable load-library issue

Tags: emacs, portable-applications

I run emacs off a usb while at work latest win32 FSF vanilla zip and Org 8.2.4

```
loading ox-reval.el via .emacs (require 'ox-reveal) results in

Wrong type argument: stringp, ox-reveal
```

If one executes M-x load-library after emacs has initilized, the library loads and works correctly.

To avoid having copy .emacs and .emacs.d to appdata\roaming on every system i use. I utilises a modified site-start.el that sets the home and loadpath env variables

```
(defvar usb-drive-letter (substring data-directory 0 3)) (defvar usb-home-dir (concat  usb-drive-letter "home/"))

(setenv "HOME" usb-home-dir)
(setenv "EMACSLOADPATH" usb-home-dir)
```

If i remove site-start.el and copy everything into the default c:\user\appdata\roaming the library loads propery via .emacs (confusing)

I use org-reveal as a teacher so I'm by no means an IT speacialist but if this helps someone else or is an issue that can be fixed, I'm sure it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try putting some debugging statements in that `site-lisp.el`: calls to `message` or a call to `debug`.  IOW, investigate what is really going on, compared with what you think might be or should be going on -- at various places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is probably not the correct fix

Moving the offending lisp into site lisp correccts the error, but this will of course require break package managment as elpa will install to .emacs.d

Any thoughts ?